# pandas multi index select: How to select subset of a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have created a DataFrame with multi index named key_mat.It just likes

```
                   cnt
keys    minutes 
0000    21:01:00    1
0002    19:08:00    2
        16:07:00    1
```

I want to select a subset of key_mat using `.loc`

```
>>> key_mat.loc[['0002']] 
>>>
                   cnt
keys    minutes 
0002    19:08:00    2
        16:07:00    1
```

Now, I have a list of `keys` `key_list = ['0000','0001','0004'...]` and a list of `minutes` `minutes_list = ['19:08:00','20:07:00',...]`.I want to select `cnt` column where `keys` in `key_list` and `minutes` in `minutes_list`. I try to use `.loc` , but I just find the way `key_mat.loc[[('0000','21:01:00'),('0002','19:08:00')]]['cnt']` .But this can't satisfy my needs. I find a way to use `query` ,`key_mat.query('keys in {key_list} and minutes in {minutes_list}'.format(key_list = key_list, minutes_list =minutes_list))`.Is there a way  to use `.loc` or `.ix` to finish my task?

Answer (score 1):

You need [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), but first [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html), because error:

> KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

```
key_list = ['0000','0001','0004']
minutes_list = ['19:08:00','21:01:00']

df.sort_index(inplace=True)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[key_list,minutes_list],:])
              cnt
keys minutes     
0000 21:01:00   1
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!